# Incompatible RemoteService Exception in Gwt?

Tags: java, gwt, rpc, smartgwt

During staring of a Smart Gwt component i got following error

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IncompatibleRemoteServiceException: Invalid type      signature for
```

Can you please tell why this is coming ??

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing any compiled class files.  I suspect you changed something, and a previously compiled class is no longer compatible.

Also, if you have GWT compiler output in src/main/webapp, you will likely see the problem again I think.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide some code, i.e. the interface definitions and where you call the RPC method?

Take a look at the API reference for this Exception, maybe the described causes match your case:
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IncompatibleRemoteServiceException.html

Have you made a change to the @RemoteServiceServletPath annotation in the synchronous interface? I once had an issue with not changing the corresponding entry in web.xml file.